# Indexing numpy array using another numpy array

Tags: numpy, indexing

I have a 2D numpy array and another 2D numpy array containing specific column indexes  I want to access from the original matrix.  How can I do it efficiently ?

For example, I have the array

```
A = np.array([[4 1 4 5 2 1 2 1 2 5],
 [4 5 5 3 3 2 5 5 3 2],
 [1 3 5 5 3 5 3 5 4 5]])
```

and the array of column indexes (which has same number of rows as A)

```
ind = np.array([[7 3 6 0 4],
 [2 5 7 3 8],
 [7 0 3 6 4]])
```

Now, I can access the elements of A corresponding to ind such that I can do A[ind] = 0, such that columns 7,3,6,0,4 in row 1 is 0, columns 2,5,7,3,8 in row 2 is 0 etc.